# Magento 2: Action button renderer for row in Grid

Tags: magento2, grid

I have a block that prepare a grid. [image]

In this render I want add a button that call to controller to export.

How I can agree this button to call one controller?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your render should be:

```
<?php

namespace Sistel\CouponActivity\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Column\Renderer;

class Link extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer
{
    /**
     * @var Action\UrlBuilder
     */
    protected $actionUrlBuilder;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context
     * @param Action\UrlBuilder $actionUrlBuilder
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context,
        Action\UrlBuilder $actionUrlBuilder,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->actionUrlBuilder = $actionUrlBuilder;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Render action
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $row
     * @return string
     */
    public function render(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
    {
        $href = $this->actionUrlBuilder->getUrl(
            $row->getIdentifier()
        );
        return '<a href="' . $href . '" target="_blank">' . __('Preview') . '</a>';
    }
}
```

We can take a look here: **vendor/magento/module-cms/Block/Adminhtml/Page/Grid.php**

```
'renderer' => 'Magento\Cms\Block\Adminhtml\Page\Grid\Renderer\Action',
```